# SSRS 2008 category Grouping

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, rdlc

Hoping this one will be a layup as I have been breaking my head over this for a full day or so.  I'm creating some reports for a client, and he has provided me with some reports he has done in excel that I haven recreating.  This one has the only one that has been giving me an issue.

[image: Excel Chart]

Colors and values aside, i'm trying to get the grouping the same and have so far not been successful. This is where i'm at:
[image: SSRS Chart]

In my data fields (series), I have four fields for the different ranges.  In the categories, I have one (results in ETR/NON-ETR).  I do have full control over the stored procedure that gives this data so any restructuring is not a problem.  How do I recreate this if at all possible using the report designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected from the beginning that my issue might have been data related.  My query is using a union (in both cases) to get the data based on some calculations to get my ranges.  I just changed how I was bringing back the data to reflect it differently.  Here is my original query results that produced that first chart:

[image: Old Query Results]

I then changed around my query and the union to put all the values in a single column, then added a column with static values for the ranges:

[image: New Query Results]

After some beautifying of the charts, this is what I ended up with the below chart.  My value was placed in the data section, Population in series, and range in category.  It seems like the key to getting this type of report is that there HAS to be a something to group the series by.

[image: Final Chart]

Answer (score 0):

First try changing the source data from actual # of deals to the percentage of deals completed.

Then try right clicking and going to "select data source", and then clicking on the "switch row/column" button.

Comment: In this case the customer does want to see the numbers.  Aside from that, I don't see either of those options.  The only options I have for the chart are basic formatting, and to change the dataset of the chart itself.  Just to be clear,  I am using the report designer in visual studio 2008, and not designing through SQL's BIDS. I assumed that the term SSRS was not mutually exclusive, but I could be referring to my development environment incorrectly.

Comment: Ah sorry about that I misunderstood the question, I assumed you just wanted to know how to recreate the chart in Excel.

Comment: No problem.  I have edited my tags and changed some of the wording of my question to clear up some confusion.  Thanks anyways! :)